# PaymentIntents refund event handling

Tags: express, stripe-payments

I'm refunding in my express app the amount that is paid by the user .

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.retrieve(p_id);
   const refund = await stripe.refunds.create({
      payment_intent: p_id,
      amount: Math.round(refundAmount * 100), // Convert refund amount to cents
    });
```

this is working fine

But i need to update records based on the refund events .

I have these two unhandled events :

```
Unhandled event type charge.refunded
Unhandled event type charge.refund.updated
```

I do have payments by card enabled , and in the future i will add google pay and apple ..

are these two events related to card payments only ?

lets say I have refunded a google pay or apple pay payment in my admin panel  will i get the same two events ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Stripe's description of the Charge object (https://docs.stripe.com/api/charges/object), the Charge abstraction applies to all payment methods.

If you refund an Apple or Google Pay from the panel, you'll get those same events. To check for yourself, you can create a test payment and refund it from the Dashboard in test mode to see what the charge refund event object would look like.

Answer (score 0):

When refunding a card / apple pay / google pay payment, you'll get a `charge.refunded` event.

You'll only get a `charge.refund.updated` event if the refund is updated, which really only happens if the refund fails. This can happen weeks after the refund.
The reason is that funds are returned to the issuer via the payment method, but sometimes (say, if you refund a payment over 2 months after capture), banks won't reconciliate the funds, and will eventually return them to the Stripe account. That's when the refund gets updated.

If this ever happens, there really isn't much else you can do besides refunding the customer outside of Stripe.

Comment: this is my first time working with stripe .. do I need to set a refund policy with a timeframe ...is it a good idea?

Comment: The `charge.refunded` event triggers as soon as you order the refund, but the refund won't be visible to the customer until 5-10 working days after. If the refund is processed soon after the payment (e.g. on the same day), then it is typically processed as a reversal, which is faster, and instead of being a credit item on the customer's statement, the original transaction disappears. This is all outlined in Stripe's non-dev documentation, and isn't really a dev topic. https://docs.stripe.com/refunds